# Winsock c++ , program freezes on connection to an offline server

Tags: c++, winsock

My program freezes when trying to connect to an offline server , it doesn't do that if it's online, i know it's trying to connect several times.

is there a way to do that without blocking the main code?

my connection function

```
bool WSockClient::ConnectServer(int PortNumber, char *IP)
{
SetClientSockAddr(&sockAddr, PortNumber, IP);       // Settings

if((hSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    return false;


if(connect(hSocket, (sockaddr*)(&sockAddr), sizeof(sockAddr)) != 0)     // Connect to                                     the server
    return false;

//cout << "Attempting to connect to " << inet_ntoa(sockAddr.sin_addr) << endl;

return true;
}
```

Comment: show what code is blocking..........................

Comment: Yes, `connect()` waits for a response from the server. If it never comes, `connect()` doesn't return until it times out. What would you expect? A shorter timeout? How much? A second? A millisecond?

Comment: Windows has a registry entry to change the connect timeout, but it affects all processes on the machine.

Answer (score 3):

By default, a socket will be 'blocking', meaning that certain calls (like `connect`) will block the execution of your program until the operation has been completed. On MS-Windows, you can change the socket to 'non-blocking' using a call to [ioctlsocket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738573(v=vs.85).aspx).

For a non-blocking socket, the `connect` call will return immediately and you'll have to use `select` to find out if the connection was successful. You can find some additional info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625(v=vs.85).aspx)